# Select from firestore only docs in list with certain enum value

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple class Audit with few properties inside.
Using firestore and its gcp c# client I want to select all documents of Manual type (DocType).

```
[FirestoreData]
[FirestoreCollectionName("Audit")]
public class Audit
{
    [FirestoreProperty]
    string Id { get; set; }
    
    [FirestoreProperty]
    List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    
     
}

[FirestoreData]
public class Document
{
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string Abbrev { get; set; }    
    
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public DocType Type { get; set; }    
}

public enum DocType
{
    Instruction,
    Manual,
    Other
}

var db = FirestoreDb.Create(my_project_id);
CollectionReference auditRef = db.Collection("Audit");
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await auditRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

...

> how to select only audits with any document of type Manual?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have modelled the data makes this difficult as you have a `Document` object nested inside an array. There is a way to query `WhereArrayContains` but this is used generally for simple types, string, number etc.

I would have structured the data in a different way, with:

- A collection `Audits`
- a sub collection of `Documents` under each audit

This way it would be easier to do a collection group query where in "Documents" where type is "Manual"